# Why is react key not working even after giving key to the returned value

Tags: reactjs

I used `uuidv4()` but it didn't work. I even tried giving items their own id but it didn't work. here is my code.

```
<Grid container className="main-movie-container" spacing={3}>
          {movies.map((movie) => {
               return (
                      <>
                          <Grid className="sub-movie-container" key={movie.imdbID}>
                              <Card md={4} className="card">
                                  <img src={movie.Poster} alt="" />
                                  <div className="content">
                                      <p className="name">{movie.Title}</p>
                                      <p className="year">Release Date: {movie.Year}</p>
                                      <button onClick={()=>addFavourites(movie)}>Add to Favourites</button>
                                  </div>
                              </Card>
                         </Grid>
                      </>
                  )
              })}
 </Grid>
```

Comment: please provide some more information with code

Comment: it's pretty to hard to understand what your code does, can you give us a codesandbox with the whole code? or more details? You said about uuid but i can't see it in your snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ***outer-most*** element returned needs to be have the unique key, in your case it's the `<>...</>`, but React keys aren't compatible with the fragment shorthand so you'd need to fully specify `<Fragment key={movie.imdbID}>...</Fragment>`. It's actually better to get rid of that fragment since you don't need it because you already have a single wrapper (`Grid`).